# Signing a User-Defined Function with a certificate in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, functions, certificate

I'm trying to use a certificate to sign a user-defined function in SQL server (2016).  My code is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction()  
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN  
 SELECT col1, col2 FROM sometable;

GO

ADD SIGNATURE TO myfunction
BY CERTIFICATE [mycertificate] 

WITH PASSWORD = 'mypassword';

GO
```

The error message I'm getting is

> Msg 15560, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot add or drop a signature on
>   'myfunction' because only modules can be signed.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

***** Edit *****
It worked when I rewrote the function so that it wasn't in inline format:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunction()
  RETURNS @tableVariable TABLE (
  col1 int NOT NULL,
  col2 varchar(255) NOT NULL
  )
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @tableVariable (col1, col2)
   SELECT s.col1, s.col2
   FROM sometable s
   RETURN;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql) calls out that

> Inline table-valued functions cannot be signed

Comment: Unless you print them out...